# What problem does the dot solve in SPARQL queries?

Tags: sparql

In every tutorial or reference I look at `.` seems to be used at the end of every line, but it is never explained why it is there. And with the more complex queries it seems the dot is sometimes inside the `{ }` and sometimes comes immediately after. And then sometimes isn't used at all. This is driving me crazy, as without knowing its purpose I feel I'm going be troubleshooting queries by trial and error: throw a dot in and repeat, try deleting a dot and repeat.

My main question is what breaks, or what kind of queries can't be written, if you don't have `.` as part of the syntax?

Explaining in terms of "it is just like the *something* in SQL" or "does the same as the *something* in a regex" might also be helpful.

---

Example of how optional the `.` is. This (chess players born in first 3 months of 2001) can be written with 6 dots:

```
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?genderLabel ?dob
WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5;
          wdt:P106 wd:Q10873124;
          wdt:P569 ?dob.
  OPTIONAL{ ?person wdt:P21 ?gender. }.
  FILTER("2001-01-02"^^xsd:dateTime <= ?dob && ?dob < "2001-03-31"^^xsd:dateTime)
  .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".} .
}
```

But can also be written with no dots at all:

```
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?genderLabel ?dob
WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5;
          wdt:P106 wd:Q10873124;
          wdt:P569 ?dob
  OPTIONAL{ ?person wdt:P21 ?gender }
  FILTER("2001-01-02"^^xsd:dateTime <= ?dob && ?dob < "2001-03-31"^^xsd:dateTime)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en"} 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SPARQL is a language for querying [RDF triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework). Each pattern matches a triple, and the [syntax for these triple patterns](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#QSynTriples) is the same as in the [Turtle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_(syntax)) or [N3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation3) syntax. You *need* the `.` to delimit multiple triples in a list, although the final `.` is optional. If you have multiple triples with the same subject or subject-predicate, you can combine them using `,` and `;`. Whitespace is not significant in SPARQL.

Comment: Thanks. Pointing out that the final dot is optional was key. Combined with the fact that the parser quietly ignores a superfluous dot after most brackets (see example in my updated question) was the other key fact needed to make sense of the queries I've been seeing. (BTW two dots in a row _is_ forbidden!)